# how to convey html table input text value to JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

I have create this method to convent html table  input text value to json but no use can someone help me ? my json value is empty []

```
<table id="address_table" class="table" runat="server">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Province</th>
      <th>PostalCode</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="street_01" maxlength="255" required /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="city_01" maxlength="255" required  /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="province_01" maxlength="255" required  /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="postalCode_01" maxlength="7" required  /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript

```
//get data from te
$("#btnAddPerson").bind("click", function() {
  var AddressesDataJSON = $("#address_table").serializeArray();
  console.log(AddressesDataJSON);
  alert(JSON.stringify(AddressesDataJSON));
});
```

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLQ2L/)

Comment: no data form the table:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `serializeArray` either on `form` elements or form controls.

```
$("#address_table").find('input').serializeArray();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Z8KX/

Answer (score 1):

[serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) should be used on a form.  You can wrap your inputs in a form and it will work.  Here is an example.  http://jsfiddle.net/pLQ2L/1/

```
<form>
<table id="address_table" class="table" runat="server">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Province</th>
      <th>PostalCode</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="street_01" maxlength="255" required /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="city_01" maxlength="255" required  /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="province_01" maxlength="255" required  /></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="postalCode_01" maxlength="7" required  /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```